# How to change the required field of Zip/Postal Code with "not required"?

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, onepage-checkout

How to change required field of Zip/Postal code with "not required" from checkout page?
i have changed the lines 106-111 in app/design/frontend/base/default/template/persistent/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml

```
<div class="field">
                    <label for="billing:postcode"><?php echo $this->__('Zip/Postal Code') ?></label>
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <input type="text" title="<?php echo $this->__('Zip/Postal Code') ?>" name="billing[postcode]" id="billing:postcode" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getAddress()->getPostcode()) ?>" class="input-text validate-zip-international <?php// echo $this->helper('customer/address')->getAttributeValidationClass('postcode') ?>" />
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Also i have removed these lines from the file "app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Address/Abstract.php"

```
$_havingOptionalZip = Mage::helper('directory')->getCountriesWithOptionalZip();
    if (!in_array($this->getCountryId(), $_havingOptionalZip)
        && !Zend_Validate::is($this->getPostcode(), 'NotEmpty')
    ) {
        $this->addError(Mage::helper('customer')->__('Please enter the zip/postal code.'));
    }
```

But it did not completely changed that field to not required. Because when i place order, it shows a message

> "Zip/Postal Code" is a required value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change that in admin panel, itself.

Navigate to

> Admin > System > Configuration > General > Country Option > Postal Code is Optional for the following countries

You can select the countries for Zip/Postal Code optional.

[image]

Comment: from which version can I find this version? I have 1.9.0.1 and I can't find it

Comment: I've set the country in optional code. but it's not working.

Comment: If you're using the RWD theme (or a theme based on it) then you also need to add some CSS to remove the asterisk - `label[for="billing:postcode"].required:after {display: none;}` - they hid the original asterisk and added one via a pseudo element, but didn't account for people changing that setting in the admin.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure you are viewing the "DEFAULT" screen view, it won't show if yiou are viewing in any other store view